# Trying to get an AccountId32 from a string in js

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to get an accountId32 from a string. In fact , i received account address in a telegram message but i would like to use native method has of BTreeMap<AccountId32, u32>.
anyone got an idea about how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have an String and want to query a method that needs an `AccountId` type as a parameter.
See the example to get the balance of an account with the [method](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#accountaccountid32-framesystemaccountinfo):

```
account(AccountId32): FrameSystemAccountInfo
```

You can query it using PolkadotJS like this:

```js
 const ADDR = '167vSUfcfk6DPmFNbV5MJZUbacSgxNYs85YUmBhgXAFHj3fd';
 const accountInfo = await apiAt.query.system.account(ADDR);
```

You can see how PolkadotJS manages the AccountId type in its codebase: https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/types/src/generic/AccountId.ts

Update for your specific example:

The `result.individual` where you try to find the address is not an array of Account_id, is the Account_id and the points:

```
'111B8CxcmnWbuDLyGvgUmRezDCK1brRZmvUuQ6SrFdMyc3S': '84,480',
```

What I suggest you to do to compare with your String is the following:

```js
    const eraRewardPoints = await api.query.staking.erasRewardPoints(era.getNumber());
    for (const [id, points] of eraRewardPoints.individual.entries()) {
      if (id.toString() === polkadotAdressInString) {
        console.log(id.toString());
        console.log(points.toHuman());
      }
    }
```

Comment: You're correct. So yeah, i will let it down the has method and do as you said. thanks a lot.